# Reclassifying raster: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,14452099) (1,3178,9156)

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I try to reclassify a DEM file. I never had problem with this code, but with this file (actually with this folder consisting of .adf files) I get the error: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,14452099) (1,3178,9156)'
I do not understand why...
My code:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np


with rasterio.open("C:.../dem_au") as src:
    # Read as numpy array
    array = src.read()
    profile = src.profile
    array = array.copy()
    # Reclassify
    array[np.where(array <= 0)] = 0
    array[np.where(array > 0) & (array <= 300)] = 1
    array[np.where(array > 300) & (array <= 600)] = 2
    array[np.where(array > 600) & (array <= 900)] = 3
    array[np.where(array > 900) & (array <= 1200)] = 4
    array[np.where(array > 1200) & (array <= 1500)] = 5
    array[np.where(array > 1500) & (array <= 1800)] = 6
    array[np.where(array > 1800) & (array <= 2100)] = 7
    array[np.where(array > 2100) & (array <= 2400)] = 8
    array[np.where(array > 2400)] = 9

with rasterio.open("C:.../DEM_reclass.tif", 'w', **profile) as dst:
    # Write to disk
    dst.write(array)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You miss parentheses. Enclose all conditions in parentheses.

`np.where(array > 0) & (array <= 300)` -> `np.where( (array > 0) & (array <= 300) )`

```
array[np.where( (array > 0) & (array <= 300) )] = 1
array[np.where( (array > 300) & (array <= 600) )] = 2
array[np.where( (array > 600) & (array <= 900) )] = 3
array[np.where( (array > 900) & (array <= 1200) )] = 4
array[np.where( (array > 1200) & (array <= 1500) )] = 5
array[np.where( (array > 1500) & (array <= 1800) )] = 6
array[np.where( (array > 1800) & (array <= 2100) )] = 7
array[np.where( (array > 2100) & (array <= 2400) )] = 8
#             ^                                  ^
```

Comment: Thank you! I Unfortunately I get a new Error: 'Writer does not exist for driver: AIG' ... Do you know that solution, too?

Comment: Try to add `profile["driver"] = "GTiff"` before the second `with`